# Google Drive search for part of a file name

Tags: google-drive

Is there any way I can search based on the last three digits of a file name?

I have a file with many invoices that are easy to reference with the last three numbers. Is there any way I can search something like `*765` to search for ends with 765

Another example.. sometimes files are prefixed with a 0, sometimes not.. `093241251` vs `93241251` and if I just search `93241251` it will not find the 0 prefix version

Comment: Doesn't just searching on "765" work?

Comment: I thought it would too but unfortunately not.. I think if there was a space it would

Answer (score 4):

## Short Answer

Google Drive UI title search doesn't search for word variants and doesn't include wildcards.

## Workarounds

Some alternatives are:

- do a search to display all the related files, then use the browser in-page search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>),
- use Google Drive for PC/Mac to be able to use the OS file search features,
- use a Google Apps Script / Google Drive API to list the files in a index file, then use an app with more search features, i.e. Google Sheets.

## Notes

- If Google Drive search returned many results, you should scroll down before using the browser in-page search
- There are threads in the Google Drive Help Forum about disabling the use of the index to make the file search work for files in the Google Drive folder.

## References

- [Search your files - Drive
  Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2375114?hl=en)
- [windows search "don't use the index" - Google Drive Help
  Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/drive/windows$20search$20%22don$27t$20use$20the$20index%22)
- [Google Apps Script to search Google
  Drive - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722229/google-apps-script-to-search-google-drive)